How do I link GLEW (OpenGL) on a Mac M1 in vs code
I'm programming in C++ and I've already linked GLFW in the project, however, I can't figure out how to add GLEW to the project. I tried downloading it from their website but unzipping the folder gives me only the includes, nothing in the library folder. There is also only links for windows or the zip file however the website does state that it works on a mac.
The reason why I think there are supposed to have lib files is because in someone else's repo, in their dependencies folder, the subfolder lib has files for GLEW.
I'm also not sure how to update my Makefile to link GLEW into the project.
This is my Makefile and also a screen shot of how my files are stored right now.
CXX = g++
OUTPUT = app

CXX_FILES = $(wildcard ./src/*.cpp)
CXX_FLAGS = -Wall -g -std=c++17 -DGL_SILENCE_DEPRECATION

LIB_DIR = src/vendors/lib
INCLUDE_DIR = src/vendors/include

# Adjusting LDFLAGS
LDFLAGS = -lpthread -lglfw.3 -lGlew -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit

all: $(OUTPUT)

$(OUTPUT): $(CXX_FILES:.cpp=.o)
    $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) -o $@ $^ -L$(LIB_DIR) $(LDFLAGS) -Wl,-rpath,$(LIB_DIR)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) -c -o $@ $< -I $(INCLUDE_DIR)

clean:
    rm -f $(OUTPUT) $(CXX_FILES:.cpp=.o)

File storage

I tried downloading it - this is your root mistake. The latest release there is 2.1.0[07-31-17] and is very old. Use homebrew and install glfw with the command brew install glfw. Then you will use pkg-config for getting proper compiler and linker flags.

Hi, thank you. Will this give a static link or a dynamic link?

Both dynamic and static.

The glew-2.1.0.zip you downloaded comes with a README file. If you read it, you will see it contains the following simple build instructions:

Build
$ make

or, using CMake:

$ cd build
$ cmake ./cmake
$ make -j4

This generates various libGLEW* files in lib or build. (for the CMake variant)
Since you're on a mac, brew install glew is the superior option.
